# Form submit/update onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, submit

I must rebuild a form, there are two buttons, one is for increasing the value of an input and second for decrease the value, and I must delete submit button and update form always if I click on increase or decrease, i have tried this with jquery onchange:

I have read also this: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$("#increaseButton").change( function() {
   $("#quantityForm").submit();
});
```

I can't edit form, because I must work only with submit, is that possible?

Comment: Could you show the HTML elements you're working with?

Comment: There are 2 input type="button"'s, 1 input type="text", there is the value of increase or decrease, and yet submit button, but there is now to delete

Answer (score 0):

I think a click would be better here:

```
$('#increaseButton').on('click', function() {
    increaseValue(); //call a function to increase the value
    $("#quantityForm").submit(); //submits the form
});
```

what is #increaseButton? is it just a link? or actual

```
<input type="button" />
```

I don't think buttons can have a "change" event attached to them

Comment: Here is a image, +1 is to increase value: http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/3097/qxn.png

Comment: Here is jQuery included, should i include something other, i get this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on''

Comment: can you put your code on jsfiddle and share the link? that would help

Comment: Must i have this function, it is no simple way to "submit" the form?
<code>increaseValue();</code>